# How do I return 2 values from a struct in Swift if I use randomElement()?

Tags: swift, struct

I'm building a quiz app in Swift where I've just figured out how to randomize the questions. I want my app to show the category of the current question in the top of the screen, however since it randomly picks a question, I can't really figure out how to get the correct category to show, according to the question that is on the 
screen.

My struct questions are built like this:

```
Question(q: "Question goes here", c: "Category goes here")
```

And the code I've got so far is this for returning the question:

```
func getQuestion() -> String {
        return question.randomElement()!.text
    }
```

For returning the category I used this bit of code:

```
func getCategory() -> String {
        return question.randomElement()!.category
    }
```

Which of course isn't right, because that just randomly picks a category instead of showing the category linked to the question it picks.

Example:

```
Question(q: "Question about B", c: "Category A")
Question(q: "Question about A", c: "Category C")
Question(q: "Question about C", c: "Category B")
```

The above is how it behaves. Below is how it should behave:

```
Question(q: "Question about A", c: "Category A")
Question(q: "Question about B", c: "Category B")
Question(q: "Question about C", c: "Category C")
```

So it picks a random question, and a random category. But not from the same tuple. How can I do this?

Sorry if I didn't describe it right, English isn't my native language.

EDIT: Example added and rewritten my question

Comment: Why not return the `Question`, and let the caller pick for themselves whether they want its text or its category?

Comment: So in your second and third code example `question` is an array of questions, `[Question]`?

Comment: Either one of the existing answers should be correct or you need to add the definition of both `question` and `Question` to your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the goal is not clear, so there might be variants...

1. return entire question

```
func getQuestion() -> Question {
        return question.randomElement()!
    }
```

2. return tuple from question (which actually the same as above, so... not clear)

```
func getQuestion() -> (String, String) {
        let question = question.randomElement()!
        return (question.text, question.category)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let randomQuestion = questionArray.randomElement()!
let question = randomQuestion.question
let category = randomQuestion.category
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but include an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually of higher quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.